# A progress bar for scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn

Is there any way to have a progress bar to the fit method in scikit-learn ?

Is it possible to include a custom one with something like [Pyprind](https://github.com/rasbt/pyprind) ?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

If you initialize the model with `verbose=1` before calling `fit` you should get some kind of output indicating the progress.

For example `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifer(verbose=1)` provides progress output that looks like this:

```
  Iter       Train Loss   Remaining Time
     1           1.2811            0.71s
     2           1.2595            0.58s
     3           1.2402            0.50s
     4           1.2263            0.46s
     5           1.2121            0.43s
     6           1.1999            0.41s
     7           1.1876            0.39s
     8           1.1761            0.38s
     9           1.1673            0.37s
    10           1.1591            0.36s
    20           1.1021            0.29s
    30           1.0511            0.27s
    40           1.0116            0.25s
    50           0.9830            0.22s
    60           0.9581            0.19s
    70           0.9377            0.16s
    80           0.9169            0.14s
    90           0.9049            0.12s
   100           0.8973            0.10s
```

Comment: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbose'

Comment: Add the keyword to the model, not the fit method call. Also, using SVR, setting verbose=True added no output as far as I can tell.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the meta-estimators used for multiclass/multilabel don't allow such keywords. For example you can't use verbose=True as a parameter to OneVsRestClassifier(), only to the classifier you're using within it. This is unfortunate because you can't get a sense of high-level progress.

Comment: how does it know the remaining time?

Answer (score 51):

Many models support a verbose argument which gives progress (and sometimes an indication on the rate of convergence).

e.g.

`clf = MLPClassifier(verbose=True)`

([see MLPClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier) )

If you have a loop outside of the learning model, I recommend [tqdm](https://github.com/noamraph/tqdm).

Answer (score 23):

## Not all scikit-learn models support the verbose parameter

Unfortunately not all scikit-learn models allow the **verbose** parameter. Off the top of my head I can say these models **do not allow verbose parameter** (there may be more):

- [**AdaBoostClassifier**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html)
- [**DecisionTreeClassifier**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html)
- [**OneVsRestClassifier**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html)

Yet curiously [**ExtraTreesClassifier**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.html) which also belongs to [**sklearn.ensemble**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.ensemble) (just like **AdaBoostClassifier**), does allow it.

Looks like not all members of **sklearn.ensemble** share the same base properties.

Comment: [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) also.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ongoing work, basically being a sort of callback feature on scikit-learn models. See [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/24524)