# How to see the progress of vectorizer.fit (sklearn)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, verbose

Consider the following code:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(documents)
```

The `fit` function takes a long time to run when there is a lot of documents (100k in my case). How to see progress (i.e., a progress bar or a count)? There is no `verbose` option.

Comment: Sadly there is no such functionality in sklearn right now (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62203612/15751564)

Answer (score 0):

You are right there is no verbose option, but there is a possible workaround.

The `CountVectorizer` class, does some pre-processing steps like `strip_accents` (None by default as in your case) and then `lowercase` and `tokenizer` (True by default as in your case for both, because you are using the `word` analyzer with default parameters).

Considering you don't care about the progress of the pre-processing steps, the only way to get information about the progress of the method, would be to create your own `analyser` as a *callable*, which is simply a function that would do the same but also print the progress at every 10% (as an example).

But if you just want a friendly way to know how long it will take, since the computation time of CountVectorizer is linearly correlated to the input size, you can choose just a fraction of your data (randomly sampled) like 10%, process that and time it. Then you know it will take about 10x more to process everything.